# SSRS Row Number Function Not Working in PDF

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2014, ssrs-2017

I am using the below code to add a Row # column in my report:

```
Dim row AS integer
Public Function GetRow() As Integer
row = row + 1
return row
End Function
```

When running the report, the report returns 29 rows and the row column seems to be working perfectly, labeling all rows 1–29 in the preview. However, when I export to PDF, the rows in the report change from 30–58. I have no idea what is causing the issue.

Is there something that the PDF is doing that handles the function differently? Does the PDF even use the function?

If not, then what can SSRS be doing that causes the function to rerun when exporting?

Why can't SSRS just export what I see on my screen?

Comment: Could you re-tag this only with the `ssrs` version you're using?  It doesn't make sense to tag 4 different versions.

Comment: Well my question is very general affecting all versions of SSRS, also I get faster responses or more people to see my question if I add more tags.

Comment: That's not really how tags work on SO and clearly not getting you more views, as only 7 people have looked at this...  Regardless of what version this affects, your version is the one that matters when you are asking a question.

Comment: It's also highly unlikely that anyone watches 2014, 2016, or 2017 as there is a combined 540 questions in those tags.

Comment: Maybe add a new function to set `row` to 0? It seems like it's picking the counting up from the initial rendering. Maybe put the function call in the table header. `="Table Header text" & code.ResetRow()`? Does it work correctly if you run a subscription to export to PDF?

Comment: @Steve-o169 540 seems like a reason to tag **more** questions with all pertinent versions - or just combine them into one generic SSRS tag. Otherwise SSRS-2050 will be out and SE will still be using the 2012 tag.

Comment: @HannoverFist I suppose that's true, but there's no reason to tag a single question with ALL of them at once.  Some SSRS issues relate to a specific issue that has changed from version to version such as an issue I saw with a CSV question that was affected by upgrading from 2005 to 2012.  I would agree that there should be a more generic SSRS tag, but this sort of tagging doesn't benefit anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just display the row number you can use SSRS function. just put this code in your tablix column in which you want to display row number.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!ProductId.Value, CountDistinct, "{name of dataset}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your function isn't working correctly, but there's an easier way.  SSRS has a built-in `RowNumber` keyword.  You should just be able to put the keyword in the table with the dataset you're using in parenthesis as a parameter of the function.

```
=RowNumber("yourDatasetHere")
```

You could also use `=RowNumber(Nothing)` to specify that the function should use the outermost dataset used in the table.

Comment: Well all that gave me was a bunch of random numbers with some going over 1,000. At least the PDF and preview match though so that's good. I forgot to mention however that each row is its own group that adds up multiple rows from the dataset together into one row in the matrix. This is why I prefer to use the function because the function only counts the number of rows that are visible in the report matrix (only 29), not the number of rows from the dataset (which could be thousands).

Comment: @K.Ventura RowNumber shouldn't pull anything from the dataset and it should work for your purposes... [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-rownumber-function?view=sql-server-2017) shows that it only counts rows in the report. Perhaps you need to set the scope as the name of the row or column group.

Comment: Well I tried everything that the document said, including scoping by the row group and nothing worked. I think I'm just going to have to go with Plan B, doing my own custom row number field in the dataset. In the meantime, I think I'll wait and see if anyone else responds to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into an issue where my alignment was off on PDF but was fine elsewhere. I had to put page breaks using `=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/37)`.

That might not be what is causing your issue, but for me, when I forced a finite number of rows on each page, it fixed it for me. Sometimes I've had to group things, or do things that didn't make sense to fix it.